# Angularjs trigger ng-repeat on each for-loop iteration complete in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have no idea how to write the title in a more understandable way. So bear with me.

**I have tags. I have posts**

*Each post has 2 or 3 or more associated tags.*

**My aim:**

To list all the tags and to list all the specific posts underneath those tags.

---

Here's a clear picture

> **Tag1**
>
> *Post1 Post2 Post3*
>
> **Tag2**
>
> *Post4 Post1*
>
> **Tag3**
>
> *Post3*

Ok. Now, I'm using two functions in my controller to do this job.

One is to get the list of tags and other is to get the posts for each tag.

Hereafter,

```
  $scope.tags = null;
  $scope.tagPosts = null;     

 var getTags = function(callback){

   $http.get('/tags').success(function(result){

    $scope.tags = result;
    callback();


  }).error(function(e){
     console.log(e);
  });


 };




var getPostsByTags = function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tags.length; i++){
      var currentTag = $scope.tags[i];
      $http.get('/posts/tag/' + currentTag.name).success(function(result){

      $scope.tagPosts = result;
       // Printing all the posts correctly
      console.log($scope.tagPosts); 

    }).error(function(e){

        console.log(e);

      });
   }

}

getTags(function(){
    getPostsByTags();
 });
```

*And in the view*

```
 <div class="single-list" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <h3 style="border-bottom: 3px solid #e2e2e2; padding-bottom:10px;"><a href="#">{{  tag.name }} ( {{ tag.used }} )</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in tagPosts">
            <span>
              <a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
            </span>
            <span class="pull-right">{{ post.date }}</span>

          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
```

So I'm printing all the tags first then printing the posts associated with each tag. Here, I have used `ngRepeat` twice. The problem is it's only printing the last post from my database under each tag and not the rest though it's consoling out all the posts in the correct order.

This is because, in `$scope.tagPosts` it's replacing the result with new result till the last iteration where only a single post is associated with the last tag

So, is it possible to trigger the second ng-repeat after every for loop completion? Or is it possible to do something with the `$scope.tagPosts` or any other tricks?

Hope I made the problem clear.

Comment: not getting your problem ?

Comment: @NeerajSharma which part?

Comment: did you mean, you want to push you last updated record into you array?

Comment: @NeerajSharma Absoulutely not. I meant more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in the way you are assigning the result to `$scope.tagPosts`. It is an array thats why it should be appended a new result not directly assigned.

Try this:

```
$scope.tagPosts = [];  // at the beginning of controller

....

$scope.tagPosts.push(result);  // inside your for loop
```

**UPDATE**

From the result, seems like `tagPosts` is an array of arrays! That's why you will need to do another `ng-repeat`:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post_arr in tagPosts">
    <span ng-repeat="post in post_arr">
        <span>
          <a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </span>
        <span class="pull-right">{{ post.date }}</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Ok. Can you elaborate a bit on the display part? The `ng-repeat` part, because it's not displaying any posts currently.

Comment: @SagnikChakraborti can you console out what you have in `$scope.tagPosts` and `$scope.tags`?

Comment: Yes I did, `$scope.tagPosts` is listing out arrays where each array contains different Objects which is post objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
(1) In your controller it should be

```
var getPostsByTags = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tags.length; i++){
      var currentTag = $scope.tags[i];
      $http.get('/posts/tag/' + currentTag.name).success(function(result){

      currentTag.tagPosts = result;
       // Printing all the posts correctly
      console.log($scope.tagPosts); 
    }).error(function(e){
        console.log(e);
      });
   }
}
```

(2) In the view, replace the

```
 <div class="single-list" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <h3 style="border-bottom: 3px solid #e2e2e2; padding-bottom:10px;"><a href="#">{{  tag.name }} ( {{ tag.used }} )</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in tag.tagPosts">
            <span>
              <a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
            </span>
            <span class="pull-right">{{ post.date }}</span>

          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
```

I think the problem here is the inner ng-repeat loop traverse the variable $scope.tagPosts, which is updated by every ajax call that get post from backend. So after all ajax call finished, this variable is been updated as the value of posts with last tag, so you only see the post with the last tag in tag array.

Comment: angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot set property 'tagPosts' of undefined. For the view to get the `$scope.tags[i].tagPosts`, what will I set outside the function? I can't do `$scope.tags[i].tagPosts = null`. right?

Comment: Use currentTag.tagPosts =  result, since this is inside for loop so we can not rely on the i value. Basically I want the data should be save in a 2D array, the outer ng-repeat loop for each tag, and the inner ng-repeat loop through all the posts which saved inside each tag object.

Comment: I got what you are trying to do. But I need to get access to the result so putting it in `currentTag.tagPosts` is not allowing me to access it. Can you write the answer more clearly specifying the controller and the ng-repeat part along with the variable definition?

Comment: `var getPostsByTags = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tags.length; i++){
      var currentTag = $scope.tags[i];
      $http.get('/posts/tag/' + currentTag.name).success(function(result){
      currentTag.tagPosts = result;
       // Printing all the posts correctly
      console.log($scope.tagPosts); 
    }).error(function(e){
        console.log(e);
      });
   }
}`

Comment: You just did what I did. Edit and update your answer properly.

Comment: `<div class="single-list" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <h3 style="border-bottom: 3px solid #e2e2e2; padding-bottom:10px;"><a href="#">{{  tag.name }} ( {{ tag.used }} )</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in tag.tagPosts">
            <span>
              <a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
            </span>
            <span class="pull-right">{{ post.date }}</span>

          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 </div>`  Still learning how to format code here, can you read it?

Comment: Nah. Can you? Format the code in the answer that you wrote, Not in the comment. Edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a filter like this:

In your js:

```
      $scope.postsToFilter = function(){
    indexedPosts = [];
    return $scope.posts;
  }
  $scope.filterPosts =function(post){
    var postIsNew = indexedPosts.indexOf(post.tagname) == -1;
    if(postIsNew){
      indexedPosts.push(post.tagname)
    }
    return postIsNew;
  }
```

And in your HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="t in postsToFilter() | filter:filterPosts">
 <h1>{{t.tagname}}</h1> 
  <div ng-repeat="p in posts | filter:{tagname: t.tagname} : true">
    {{p.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vBae0aniBZXeAKTpzPYE?p=preview).  I believe this is what you are trying to do.  Let me know if it is not.

Comment: I checked your plunker code. But there's a difference. Under each posts there are several tags and not a single tag. So the `tagname:` in your code will contain an array of tags

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am confused about what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an array will solve your problems, where each element is of type {tag:TagObject,posts:PostObject[]}.For an example:

```
$scope.data =[]
 var getTags = function(callback){
   $http.get('/tags').success(function(result){
    $scope.tags = result;
    callback();
  }).error(function(e){
     console.log(e);
  });
var getPostsByTags = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.tags.length; i++){
      var currentTag = $scope.tags[i];
      $http.get('/posts/tag/' + currentTag.name).success(function(result){
      $scope.data.push({tag:currentTag,posts:result});
       // Printing all the posts correctly
      console.log($scope.tagPosts); 
    }).error(function(e){
        console.log(e);
      });
   }
```

and in your html:

```
 <div class="single-list" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" ng-repeat="tag in data">
    <h3 style="border-bottom: 3px solid #e2e2e2; padding-bottom:10px;"><a href="#">{{  tag.tag.name }} ( {{ tag.tag.used }} )</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in tag.posts">
            <span>
              <a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
            </span>
            <span class="pull-right">{{ post.date }}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Haven't tested the above but i think it looks ok